# What is the connection between backend and api like using bottle python?

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, bottle

I am new to bottle, and full stack development. I was wondering about the structure of the whole web-application. How's the connection really implemented, is the api code going to be in a separate file or is it going to be incorporated in the main script.

So I have a couple of classes, that are instantiated in the main script which will take user input and return values 'say dictionaries or strings'. I just can not think of a way to connect bottle to these output values, unless the bottle code was in the main script. I would upload the code but it is too big.

```
#this code is in a separate file
@post('/home')  # or @route('/login', method='POST')
def simulate():
    #windturbine
    radius = float(request.forms.get('radius'))
    noOfTurbines = float(request.forms.get('noOfTurbines'))
    windDict = windturbine(radius, noOfTurbines).Forecast_Wind_Engergy(2)
```

I would like the main program to run every time the user inputs values, but the way I implemented it so far, there is no connection between main in bottle code. The only connection I have is through the instantiated objects in the bottle code, which are obviously different from the one in main.

Comment: You could send JSON between the URLs as a POST request. What is the structure of your app?

Comment: For a form, you can have the same URL route but written twice as GET (for loading the form) and POST for handling it. There are some great examples at bottlepy.org

Answer (score 0):

Look a little about mvc it will be helpful for the code structure. You separate the routes (part where you do the request) from controller (part where all the logic comes in the way, math, querys, fors, etc.) and the models (where you put the structure of your tables or documents).

On the side where you want to make a separate api from the web app that grate because you just have one logic part for multiple apps web desktop or mobile, most of the times the people separate the web app from the api.

For communication between the apps and the api you need a authentication method, you can use oauth, jwt for example, than on all the api routes that need a logged user you ask for the oauth or jwt token on the headers, so not everybody can use your api.